# How to configure column in ExtJS 5

Tags: extjs, extjs5

In `Grid` we have `column`. In `column` we can see menu, which has 3 option : `Ascending`, `Descendind` and `column`.

1) My requirement is to  hide `column` option from `column Menu`. If is it possible, then it's good. If not, then can we hide the column Menu?

2) In column Header, Coumn name is not completely visible, because of column width. Is there any seeting in `ExtJS`, so that Column width will automatically be adjusted according to the `Column` Name ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. To disable menu completly use `menuDisabled` column config. To disable only column menu set `enableColumnHide` to `false` on grid.
2. You can use `autoSize` method on column:

   ```
   Ext.Array.each(grid.query('headercontainer>gridcolumn'), function(c) {
       c.autoSize();
   });
   ```

   It sizes column to fit content, but it seems that it works also with headers.

Comment: for #2 : where exactly we have to call it ?

Comment: Because you are interested in first place in adjusting header width, I suggest call it in `afterrender` event.